# Iterating through all columns in dataframe to multiply all numbers less than 1 by 100

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple columns where I need to #update values from 0.XX% to XX.XX% format. currently I have:

```
df['GLOBAL'] = np.where(df['GLOBAL']<1, df['GLOBAL']*100,  df['GLOBAL'])
```

but this requires a new line for every column name. I'm trying to iterate through all of my columns.

I've tried writing a simple function:

```
def update_ot(dataframe):
    for x in dataframe:
        if x < 1:
            return x *100
        else:
            return x
```

but when I apply it:

```
df = df.apply(update_ot)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: ("'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'", 'occurred at index category')
```

Comment: By "`0.XX%`", do you mean that the dataframe contains the _string_ `'0.XX%'`?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. Have you done any research, read the Pandas docs?

Answer (score 4):

Iterating over a dataframe iterates over the column **names**. So `x` in your loop is the name of a particular column.

But you don't necessarily need a loop. Dataframes also have a method `where` that works similarly to numpy's:

```
df.where(df >= 1, df * 100)
```

Note that the value is changed if condition is *false*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import pandas as pd 
foo = [{
'Language': 'Python',
'Percent grow': 56
}, {
'Language': 'Java',
'Percent grow': 34
}, {
'Language': 'C',
'Percent grow': 25
}, {
'Language': 'C++',
'Percent grow': 12
}, {
'Language': 'go',
'Percent grow': 5
}]

df = pd.DataFrame(foo, index=pd.RangeIndex(0, len(foo)))
print(df)
```

Initial value

```
       Language  Percent grow
      Python            56
        Java            34
           C            25
         C++            12
          go             5
```

Update the cell in “Percent grow “  where value is less then 6.

```
df.loc[df['Percent grow'] <6  ,'Percent grow']= df['Percent grow'] *100

print (df)
```

Result

```
  Language  Percent grow
   Python            56
   Java              34
   C                 25
   C++               12
   go                500
```